# dotnet publish runs before prepublish finishes

Tags: webpack, .net-core, publish

My `dotnet publish` command does not wait for prepublish to finish before doing the publish step.  Results is missing content published.

In my scenario,  prepublish runs webpack to generate wwwroot.  But publish happens before prepublish finishes resulting in a missing wwwroot.  If I publish againg,  since wwwroot now exist,  it gets published correctly.

Here's the relevant project.json section

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "appsettings.json",
        "Views",
        "web.config",
        "wwwroot",
        "AppStore/dist"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot/dist/*.map"
    ]
  },


  "scripts": {
      "prepublish": [
        "npm install",
        "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod",
        "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"
      ],
  },
```

Anybody else seen this?  running Dotnet Core 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177

Answer (score 1):

I have found [this](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5498) issue on dotnet/cli which describes your behaviour. There is a [follow up](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/114) in the aspnet/websdk repository which also describes a work around:

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- Exclude old script and font files from publish output-->
    <ItemGroup>
        <PrevScriptFiles Include="wwwroot\**" />
        <ResolvedFileToPublish Remove="@(PrevScriptFiles->'%(FullPath)')" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <DistFiles Include="wwwroot\**" />
        <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
            <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

The latest comments show that this is not needed for a long time:

> This change is already available in the latest CLI (and should be available in an upcoming VS release).

But anyhow, just wanted to post the workaround ...